# How does one Dispose an object that is set in foreach?

Tags: idisposable

```
foreach(var someDisposableObject in listOfDisposableObjects)
{
    //some code
    someDisposableObject.Dispose(); //current code contains something like this.
}
```

Is there safe way, like a `using` clause to use in this scenario?

For my second iteration (before getting responses) I changed the code to

```
foreach(var someDisposableObject in listOfDisposableObjects)
{
    try
    {
        //some code
    }
    finally
    {
        someDisposableObject.Dispose(); //current code contains something like this.
    }
}
```

though

```
foreach(var someDisposableObject in listOfDisposableObjects)
{
    using( someDisposableObject )
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

is much more tidy and most likely safer.

Comment: When and where are the objects created?

Comment: Jeffrey, the scenario is looping through sub-webs in SharePoint, so they're created outside my code. Sharepoint is a little funny about when you should dispose and there is a lot of code that doesn't safely dispose out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may be your best bet:

```
try
{
    foreach(var someDisposableObject in listOfDisposableObjects) 
    { 
        //some code 
    } 
}
finally
{
    foreach(var someDisposableObject in listOfDisposableObjects) 
    { 
        someDisposableObject.Dispose();
    } 
}
```

EDITED TO ADD:

If you absolutely have to dispose of every object no matter what, then you can do this:

```
    private static void DoStuff(IEnumerable<IDisposable> listOfDisposableObjects)
    {
        using (var enumerator = listOfDisposableObjects.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                DoStuffCore(enumerator);
        }
    }

    private static void DoStuffCore(IEnumerator<IDisposable> enumerator)
    {
        using (var someDisposableObject = enumerator.Current)
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                DoStuffCore(enumerator);

            // Do stuff with someDisposableObject                
        }
    }
```

Comment: This could fail in the finally block.

Comment: Sure it could. If you're concerned that the Dispose method itself could throw, then you'll have to do something else.

Comment: @Greg Ogle - OK, I added a solution that will *always* dispose of the objects. (Unless there's a catastrophic error, of course. I can't stop a power failure!)

Answer (score 3):

I would say your Dispose code should be outside of this foreach.

The key point you haven't addressed in your sample is how the list of disposable objects is generated.  What happens if an exception is thrown while you are generating the list of disposable objects?  You will want to dispose those that you have created so far.

Ideally you want a container that implements IDisposable to hold your disposable objects.  If your disposable objects implement IComponent, then System.ComponentModel.Container is what you need.  If not, you may have to roll your own.

Code might look something like:

```
using(Container container = new Container())
{
    // Generate list and add each element to the container
    for (...)
    {
        someDisposableComponent = ...;
        container.Add(someDisposableComponent);
        listOfDisposableObjects.Add(someDisposableComponent);
    }

    ... 

    foreach(var someDisposableObject in listOfDisposableObjects)
    {
        ... some code ...
    }
}
```

I suggest you post code that generates the list if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

Since there was no mention of the need to dispose of all un-enumerated items.
We can handle it safely as below as we don´t leave room for code execution between the foreach and using block.

```cs
foreach(var disposableObject in listOfDisposableObjects) using (disposableObject)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: If `//some code` throws an error, then any disposable objects in the list after the current one will not be disposed. This code only differs from the OP in that the object currently being processed will be disposed.

Comment: I just didn't know that was valid/legit/possible.  Simple.  Thanks.

Comment: I agree with Jeffrey. This answer is seriously flawed and should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: @JeffreyLWhitledge can you please explain why?  I would have interpreted the code as a try { //some code } finally { if (someDisposableObject != null) (IDisposable)someDisposableObject.Dispose(); }  If //some code throws an exception, it will dispose this object, and the foreach will pass the exception up rather than enumerate the next item

Comment: @MAfifi—The problem is that every object in the collection needs to be disposed. Before the `foreach` loop even begins, we have a collection of objects, and every object in that collection needs to be disposed, whether `//some code` completes or not for any of the previous objects. This is different from the normal case, in which the object is created inside the parenthesized portion of the `using` statement. If `//some code` throws an exception, then the `foreach` loop may be terminated before every object in the collection has its chance to be supplied to the `using` statement.

Comment: @JeffreyLWhitledge that's correct, but foreach is a single threaded operation.  Whilst the using statement is processing listOfDisposableObjects[n], foreach hasn't created an instance (yet) of listOfDisposableObjects[n + 1]

Comment: @MAfifi - Threading doesn't enter into it. In this scenario, all of the disposable objects are created before the `foreach` begins. The original question wasn't clear on that, which is why I asked for clarification in the comments to the question. Please read those comments.

Comment: @JeffreyLWhitledge thanks that makes sense in that case (when all the objects are pre-created)